# Python Arrays and Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

My array consists of 400 values, I would like to assign the first 4 values to one matrix and next 4values to other matrix until the end of the array. So I will result in 100 Matrix consisting of 4 values.How do I do it effectively in Python?

Comment: Give a look at [np.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Comment: Did you tried something ? give some code that u have tried?

Comment: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1200 into shape(100,4). The array consists of vectors of 400 rows n 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call `A` your original array

With python lists :

```
l = [[A[4*i+j]for j in range(4)] for i in range(100)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .The values of array are 3 dimensional vectors, 1*3(rows and columns). I want to store the resulting matrices with different names like doc1, doc2.... doc100.  So doc1 matrix consists of first 4values of array,then doc2 has next 4...so on...I need to store these matrices for my further calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
a = np.arange(400).reshape((100, 4))
```

or if oyu have a list

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
a = np.array(l).reshape((100, 4))
```

as yatu suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=np.array(range(400))

a.reshape(100,4)
```

This will take less time to execute.